# Can I force WebView2 to load a specific version (older) with CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions?

Tags: c++, windows, webview2

It seams that in the current WebView2 that is online published by Microsoft is a bug.

Symptoms: We get a crash when the WebView2 window is closed. In fact when `ICoreWebView2Controller::Close` is called.

We rolled out the program in February. We don't ship any additional runtime, we just include the WebView2Loader.dll into our setup. The implementation calls `CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions`.

No changes up today. But starting from today a reproducible crash is reported from many customers. Crash dumps show that the Close function of the `ICoreWebView2Controller` is called.

In detail: We just use `CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions` and pass a `nullptr` to the `options` and to `browserexecutable` folder. So I let WebView2 to download itself. I only define a user data folder path.

Questions:

1. Without changing the code! Is it possible to change the runtime that is used? Or to force that an older runtime is used?
2. If I need to change the code! How can I influence the runtime version that is used?

Edit:
The WebView 2 version used by this customers is:
EmbeddedBrowserWebView.dll 91.00.864.59

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#fixed-version-distribution-mode

Comment: If you're using evergreen distribution you cannot pick different versions - you always get the latest. The doc Poul Bak links above tells how to obtain copies of the webview2 runtime that don't auto update, how to extract them, and how to update your code to use them. To try different versions without changing the code, you can use the WEBVIEW2_BROWSER_EXECUTABLE_FOLDER env variable described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/webview2-idl?view=webview2-1.0.864.35#createcorewebview2environmentwithoptions

Comment: I was able to install a local older version und switch to this old version using the environment variable in my test field. Thanks.
Write your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using evergreen distribution of the WebView2 Runtime you cannot pick specific versions - you always get the latest.

If you're using [fixed version distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#fixed-version-distribution-mode) of the WebView2 Runtime you can read more in the previous link of how to obtain copies of the webview2 runtime that don't auto update, how to extract them, and how to update your code to use them. Or if you want to try different fixed version webview2 runtimes without changing your code, you can use the `WEBVIEW2_BROWSER_EXECUTABLE_FOLDER` environment variable described [in the docs for CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/webview2-idl?view=webview2-1.0.864.35#createcorewebview2environmentwithoptions).